# Place the value of the progress bar in the center as it growth

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a progress bar:

[image: Progress bar]

For some reasons, I can seem to move the value of to the center.

```
.progressBar {
  border: black solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

#progressBarText {
  text-align: center;
}


<div class="progress progressBar" style="background-color: blue;" width="50%">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" id="progressBarText" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemax="100">
    50%
  </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't seem to take effect.

How can I debug this further?

Comment: Your code shows the text in the middle of the progress bar. Please update your question so that it shows a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: bootsrap i suppose ... which version ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif : I used version 3

Comment: @ObsidianAge you asked for a MCVE so why you changed his code to a snippet then ? you will simply make his question irrelevant as his code is not the complete one

Comment: @ObsidianAge : Fine, if you guys want, I will upload the JSFiddle link here .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/f6nyo0a2/

Comment: here is : https://jsfiddle.net/f6nyo0a2/4/ you are simply doing wrong with the progress, the width should be in the inner element

Comment: @ihue Just to clarify, are you trying to move the "50%" to the middle of the progress bar, like in the image?

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
#progressBarText {
     text-align: center;
     width:  100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your class **.progress-bar** add this

```
width: 50%;
```